# is possible modify a response in a GatewayFilter

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I have developed this configuration, the filter works when is pre and post option, but when I want modify the response is impossible, I have tried a lot of options but always get the response without the modification.

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class BookRoute {


  @Bean
  public RouteLocator login(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
        .route(p -> p
            .path("/book/list/**")
            .filters(f -> f.filter(loginFilter()))
            .uri("http://localhost:8080/book/list"))
        .build();
  }



  @Bean
  public GatewayFilter loginFilter() {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
      //PRE-FILTER I don't need do anything
      
      return chain.filter(exchange).then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
        //POST-FILTER 
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
           HttpStatus status = response.getStatusCode();
           if (status != null && status.equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {

             //IS POSSIBLE MODIFY THE RESPONSE HERE??
             //I want add a field in the json response
           
}
      }));
    };
  }

}
```

I want add a field in response body when status is ok 200

Comment: Spring Cloud Gateway has a built-in filter to do that. Check this out https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#modify-a-response-body-gatewayfilter-factory